# "adjective" or "noun" for answering the question word "What"

Tags: exam-questions

Given Sentence:

> Girls  who  are  tall usually  long  to  be  dainty  and  small,  and  vice  versa;  plump  girls  with  rosy  round  faces  would  love  to be  pale  and  delicate;  slender  girls  with  very  white  skin  hate  their  pale  and  colourless  look.

Question:

> What do dainty and small girls want to be?

Possible Answer:

> 1. Dainty and small girls want to be tall.[adjective complement]
> 2. Dainty and small girls want to be tall girls.[noun complement]

Which will be appropriate answer for this type of "What" question, "adjective" or "noun"?

Comment: Either response is fine. It's just as syntactically valid to say *I want **to be happy** when I grow up* as it is to say *I want **to be a doctor** when I grow up*.

Comment: Where did you find these sentences? The subject matter here makes me cringe.

Comment: @J.R. Yes you have to wonder if English-language programs shouldn't include a mandatory introductory cultural orientation.

Comment: @Andrew - I suppose it might be from a curriculum that was developed 50 or 60 years ago, and just hasn't been updated with the times. If not, though, someone could use a sensibility slap.

Comment: @J.R.  Sad to say but there are parts of the United States where this might still be a reasonable thing to say in casual conversation, or even teach in the classroom.  But it's not something I would suggest English learners use *anywhere*.

Answer (score 13):

Both make sense and are grammatical, but in practice you would use answer (1). You don't need "girls" to be repeated as it is unambiguous.

If, however, you wanted to express that dainty and small girls actually wanted to be tall giraffes, then you would need to include the noun at the end.